# Make CSS Flex Elements Ignore Container Element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working to create a component similar to [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), but I'm running into an issue with flex and wrapping.  The gist is that each "chip" in the pseudo textbox needs to be in a container that does not also contain the actual text input, but I need those chips to be treated as a flex element on the same basis as the `input`.

My HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="chipContainer">
    <div class="chip">Chip1</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip2</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip3</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip4</div>
  </div>
  <input class="textbox" type="text">
</div>
```

This [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/OisQWq3c2K3KVGqmxhFw?p=preview) is more complete and has styles roughly equivalent to what I'm working with currently.

```css
.box {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.chip {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  flex: auto;
}
.textbox {
  border: none;
  background: #fdd;
  font-size: 18px;
  flex: auto;
}
.textbox:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.chipContainer {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="chipContainer">
    <div class="chip">Chip1</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip2</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip3</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip4</div>
  </div>
  <input class="textbox" type="text">
</div>
<br>
<div class="box">
  <div class="chipContainer">
    <div class="chip">Chip1</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip2</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip3</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip4</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip5</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip6</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip7</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip8</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip9</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip10</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip11</div>
  </div>
  <input class="textbox" type="text">
</div>
```

As you can see, after enough chips have been added to the `.box` container the `.chipContainer` will begin to wrap them, but `.chipContainer` remains a block element and pushes the `input` down to a new line entirely.

This [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/aBwFnrCaOIAXRvL2oKQA?p=preview) demonstrates my goal.  The layout can be achieved fairly easily once `.chipContainer` is removed, however it's a fairly essential element in the component's structure, and I would prefer to solve this without removing it, if possible.

```css
.box {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.chip {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  flex: auto;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 60px;
}
.textbox {
  border: none;
  background: #fdd;
  font-size: 18px;
  flex: auto;
  min-width: 250px;
}
.textbox:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.chipContainer {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="chip">Chip1</div>
  <div class="chip">Chip2</div>
  <div class="chip">Chip3</div>
  <div class="chip">Chip4</div>
  <input class="textbox" type="text">
</div>
<br>
<div class="box">
  <div class="chip">Chip1</div>
  <div class="chip">Chip2</div>
  <div class="chip">Chip3</div>
  <div class="chip">Chip4</div>
  <div class="chip">Chip5</div>
  <div class="chip">Chip6</div>
  <div class="chip">Chip7</div>
  <div class="chip">Chip8</div>
  <div class="chip">Chip9</div>
  <input class="textbox" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Display Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/) instroduces [`display: contents`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-outside-contents):

> The element itself does not generate any boxes, but its children and
>   pseudo-elements still generate boxes as normal. For the purposes of
>   box generation and layout, the element must be treated as if it had
>   been replaced with its children and pseudo-elements in the document
>   tree.

So you just need

```css
.chipContainer {
  display: contents;
}
```

```css
.box {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.chip {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  flex: auto;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 60px;
}
.textbox {
  border: none;
  background: #fdd;
  font-size: 18px;
  flex: auto;
}
.textbox:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.chipContainer {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="chipContainer">
    <div class="chip">Chip1</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip2</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip3</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip4</div>
  </div>
  <input class="textbox" type="text">
</div>
<br>
<div class="box">
  <div class="chipContainer">
    <div class="chip">Chip1</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip2</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip3</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip4</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip5</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip6</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip7</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip8</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip9</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip10</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip11</div>
  </div>
  <input class="textbox" type="text">
</div>
```

However, note it's not widely supported yet.

Comment: It looks like this is what I'm after, browser support notwithstanding. Thanks!

Comment: Would be perfect except "not widely supported" is a bit of an understatement as I believe it is only supported in Firefox as of January 21, 2016 (no chrome, IE, safari, or opera support even with latest versions)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `flex-grow` and `flex-basis`:

However values for these properties should change based on how much child elements `.chipContainer` have.

The ideia is (using your example), `.chipContainer` is a flex item of `.box` but also a flex container for its children. As a flex item it should be 4 sizes bigger than `.textbox` because there are four `.chip`, so we use `flex-grow:4` and `flex-basis:4px`.

`.textbox` and `.chip` should have the same size, so all of them have `flex-basis:1px` and `flex-grow:1`.

```css
.box, .chipContainer
{
    display: flex;
}

.textbox, .chip
{
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 1px;
    border-width: 0;
}

.chipContainer
{
    flex-grow: 4;
    flex-basis: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="chipContainer">
    <div class="chip">Chip1</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip2</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip3</div>
    <div class="chip">Chip4</div>
  </div>
    <input type="text" class="textbox" />
</div>
```

The only problem with this approach is that at least on Chrome the borders of input text was making the calculations fails and it was getting 4 pixels more than other boxes, I removed borders from all items so them now have the same width.

Comment: This doesn't seem to account for a variable number of `.chip` elements, or wrapping them within `.box`.

Comment: well, this is the only solution I can think on, you can set basis and grow using javascript or any server language

Comment: I think I can make do with setting basis and grow dynamically, but wrapping is essential.

Comment: got it, I had missed that point from your question, I read it again and now I see the wrapping issue